# Visual studio code interpreting system files as source control

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using vscode for a long time and I never had a problem like this before.

Whenever I try using vscode, it works fine but it says I have 10000 pending changes, I've checked what they are, and they're just base files like `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Adobe\OOBE\filesync.db`. I tried discarding all but it gave me an error, `Git: warning: failed to remove AppData/Local/Adobe/ANEData.db: Invalid argument`. I even deleted my `.vscode` folder in the hopes it would help. It did not.

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you have a `.git` folder in your `C:\Users\myuser` folder? where is your Workspace folder?

Comment: @rioV8 yes I do (although I don't know what it's for), if you mean workspace folder as in where I have all my code files, it's on `C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Stuff\Code`

Comment: A workspace folder is the folder you have opened in VSC, the name is shown in the title bar of the file explorer

Comment: Then yeah, that's my folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had an empty `.git` folder within my user folder. This made it think everything in my `Users` folder was a repo file. So deleting the empty folder fixes it.